# Bind tables by condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server. Please help me to solve my problem.

I have two tables `products` and `returned`. I want to get all product's names and returned amounts from `returned` based on the `products_id` in `returned`.

With a condition that if there isn't products_id it must show 'not entered yet'.

Like this example

[image]

Comment: can you add some example data

Comment: explore [Joins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-2017). You can use outer joins based on your requirement.

Comment: for example, if there is no id product from products in returned it must show that product and 'not entered yet' same as above picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` :

```
SELECT p.product_name, 
       isnull(cast(r.amount as varchar(255)), 'not retunrned yet') as returned_amount
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     returned r
     ON R.products_id = p.products_id;
```

This would return non-aggregated data if you want to show total value return then aggregated your data using `group by` clause.

```
SELECT p.product_name, 
       ISNULL(CAST(SUM(r.amount) as varchar(255)), 'not retunrned yet')) as returned_amount
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     returned r
     ON R.products_id = p.products_id
GROUP BY p.product_name;
```

Comment: can you please tell where is my mistake. I am trying to join tree tables. it show one product more than one----------`  SELECT mah.prod_name, 
       isnull(cast(ret.amount as varchar(255)), 'not returned yet') as returned_amount, isnull(cast(giv.amount as varchar(255)), 'not given yet') as given_amount
  FROM  mahsulot mah,returned ret,given giv
  LEFT JOIN mahsulot ON id_mahsulot = id_returned
  LEFT JOIN returned ON id_return = id_returned
  group by mah.prod_name, ret.amount, giv.amount;`

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want something like this:

```
select p.product_name,
       coalesce( convert(varchar(255), sum(r.amount)), 'not entered yet') as returned_amount
from products p left join
     returns r
     on p.product_id = r.product_id
group by p.product_name;
```

This assumes that `returns` could have multiple rows for a single product.

Note that `amount` is presumably a number.  In SQL, you would normally just use `NULL` to represent that there are no returns, and handle a string replacement in the application layer.